# Handling multi-layer many-to-many relationship in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have three entities:

1. User
2. Role, and
3. Right

Each `User` has several `Roles`, and each `Role` has several `Right`. The class definition is like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="...")
public class User {
    ...        
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(...)
    private List<Role> UserRoles; 
}
...
@Entity
@Table(name="...")
public class Role{
    ...        
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(...)
    private List<Right> RoleRights; 
}
```

I want to do the following two tasks:

1. Show the Right for each User.
2. Search Users by their Right.

Currently I've implemented (1) by the following:

```
// some method in the data access layer
public List<User> GetUser(){
    ...
    userList = (List<User>) someHibernateCriteria.list();
    if(userList != null && userList.size() > 0)
    {
        for(User user : userList)
        {
            Hibernate.initialize(user.getUserRoles());
            for(Role role : user.getUserRoles())
            {
                Hibernate.initialize(role.getRoleRights());
            }
        }
    }

    return userList;
}
...
```

Display code for `jsp`, looping the `userList` and putting each `user` in a html `table row`

```
<td>
    ${user.stringDescription}
</td>
<td>
    <ul>
    <c:forEach items="${user.userRoles}" var="role">
        <c:forEach items="${role.roleRights}" var="right">
            <li>${right.stringDescription}</li>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</td>
```

And I do (2) similarly too, i.e. populate the intermediate List of Role for getting the relation between User and Right. I wonder if this is a good practice or if there is a more efficient way to do the tasks.

Comment: You should have bi-directional mapping in each of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that logic is already implemented in the Spring Security